# How to use 2 differents block of code in the same worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run 2 different codes in the same worksheet.

I thought It worked when I tried, but when I ran the first block of code, it didn't work and stopped me at my second block of code for debugging.

The second block of code works perfectly fine.

Here are my 2 blocks of codes:

The first code is to copy names from one sheet to another. The second code is to delete information in cell `AE` if cell `D` = `Oui`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'THIS IS MY FIRST BLOCK OF CODE

    If Target.Column = 2 Or Target.Column = 3 Then
        Dim wsSuiviDeProjet As Worksheet
        Set wsSuiviDeProjet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SuiviDeProjet")     
     On Error GoTo EH
         Dim NewRowCount As Long
         NewRowCount = Target.Row
         If wsSuiviDeProjet.Cells(NewRowCount, 2).Value <> "" And wsSuiviDeProjet.Cells(NewRowCount, 3).Value <> "" Then                    
             Dim wsMonitoring As Worksheet
             Set wsMonitoring = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Monitoring")
             Dim wsCoordonnées As Worksheet
             Set wsCoordonnées = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("coordonnées")           
             If wsSuiviDeProjet.Cells(NewRowCount, 3).Value = "oui" Then                        
                 Dim LastRowMonitoringSheet As Integer
                 LastRowMonitoringSheet = wsMonitoring.Cells(wsMonitoring.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row                           
                 Dim dataExists As Boolean
                 dataExists = False
                 Dim ii As Integer
                     For ii = 2 To LastRowMonitoringSheet
                         If wsMonitoring.Cells(ii, 1).Value = wsSuiviDeProjet.Cells(NewRowCount, 2).Value Then
                             dataExists = True
                             Exit For
                         End If
                     Next ii               
                         If Not dataExists Then
                             wsMonitoring.Rows(LastRowMonitoringSheet).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                             LastRowMonitoringSheet = wsMonitoring.Cells(wsMonitoring.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row                                           
                             wsMonitoring.Cells(LastRowMonitoringSheet - 1, 1).Value = wsSuiviDeProjet.Cells(NewRowCount, 2).Value                                         
                         Else                                           
                         End If              
                 End If               
                 Dim LastRowCoordinatesSheet As Integer
                 LastRowCoordinatesSheet = wsCoordonnées.Cells(wsCoordonnées.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row                    
                 Dim dataExistsM As Boolean
                 dataExistsM = False                           
                 Dim i As Integer
                     For i = 5 To LastRowCoordinatesSheet
                         If wsCoordonnées.Cells(i, 1).Value = wsSuiviDeProjet.Cells(NewRowCount, 2).Value Then
                             dataExistsM = True
                             Exit For
                         End If
                     Next i                            
                     If Not dataExistsM Then
                         wsCoordonnées.Cells(LastRowCoordinatesSheet + 1, 1).Value = wsSuiviDeProjet.Cells(NewRowCount, 2).Value
                         'MsgBox ("data inserted in COORDINATES SHEET")                                
                     Else                                
                     End If                                                       
             End If

    EH:

         Call CopyHighlightedData_Click
     End If   

    'THIS IS MY SECOND BLOCK OF CODE

     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
         If Target = "oui" Then
             Range("AE" & Target.Row).Clear
         End If
     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a strange way to indent your code, makes it hard to read. However, it should work - but I would create two subroutines and call them from your event handler

Comment: why do u say it didnt work ? some error ?

Comment: This: `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then` does the same as this: `If Target.Column = 2 Or Target.Column = 3 Then` for different columns. You can add the second code in an `Else` statement for the your first block.

Comment: @LuisCurado When I run the code,  get a debbugging error box. If i click 'END', nothing happens and everything works just fine, but if I click ''debug'', it wont work anymore.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thank you.....

Comment: @Plutian what do you mean in a ```Else``` statement?  Can you please provide an example using the code I displayed ? Thank you so much

Comment: At the end of your first block of code, remove the `End If` and replace it by `Else`. Then add the `End If` back at the very end of your second block. Now the two are one single block, testing for two columns first, then for another after.

Comment: @Plutian You want me to add another ```End If``` back at the very end of my second block even though theres already one ```End If``` ? I tried and it doesnt give me anything. And I only replace the ```End If``` by ```Else```, it gives me an error : Compilation error, bloc If without End If